# make error ignored - when it shouldn't

Tags: makefile

In my make file , for a given target , I have cmd1 followed by cmd2

structure is:

( there is a tab before cmd1 and cmd2 )

target:

cmd1

cmd2

---

cmd1 fails , returning no 0 status code ( 231 )  , so make should halt ( as it has always been the case )

for some reason , i'm now getting :

make: [target] Error 231 (ignored)

and the excution goes on

any idea why?

Comment: found the reason! apparently "cmd1" had "-" at the beginning of the command - causing error to be ignored